# How to get windows service name at runtime in a c# service?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am starting multiple instances with

```
sc <server> [command] [service name] <option1> <option2>...
```

Because I need to know the service name at runtime I tried

```
    public static string getServiceName(int pid = 0)      
    {
        string result = "";

        System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service where ProcessId={0}", pid));

        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();
        foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            result = Convert.ToString(mo["Name"]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    getServiceName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
```

Without success.

Answer (score -2):

How about something like [Process.GetCurrentProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: The code in the question is already calling that method, so what exactly are you suggesting to do differently?

Comment: Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName

Comment: So is the Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName the Windows service name?

Comment: ProcessName does not get you what you want. Your initial code should work fine, but if it is getting called before the service is running, it will not have a valid processid.  Perhaps try calling it OnStart.

Comment: Im calin this onStart. Is there something after start related event?

Comment: If this is executed in the visual studio debugger, it will not work.  The service needs to be installed and running for the wmi query to work.